# multiply two columns in a tab delimited text file using awk

Tags: awk

How can I multiply column col23 by 10 and col24 by 20 using awk?
Thanks for looking at this :)

```
city    town    id  col1   col2   col3   col4   col21   col22   col23   col24
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
dublin  town1   1   1       2       3       5       1       2       3       4
dublin  town1   2           2       8       10      6       7       8       9
dublin  town1   3           12      13      15      11      12      13      14
dublin  town2   4   1       2       3       5       1       2       3       4
dublin  town2   5   6       7       8       10      6       7       8       9
dublin  town2   6   11      12      13      15      1       12      13      14
```

I tried this but does not seem to work
awk -F, '{$10*10;print}' OFS=, inputFile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As col23 is in col10 and col24 in col11, something like this can make it:

```
$ awk '/dublin/{$10*=10; $11*=20}1' OFS="\t" file
city    town    id  col1   col2   col3   col4   col21   col22   col23   col24
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
dublin  town1   1       1       2       3       5       1       2       30      80
dublin  town1   2       2       8       10      6       7       8       90      0
dublin  town1   3       12      13      15      11      12      13      140     0
dublin  town2   4       1       2       3       5       1       2       30      80
dublin  town2   5       6       7       8       10      6       7       80      180
dublin  town2   6       11      12      13      15      1       12      130     280
```

We get the record 10 and 11 and multiply *10, *20 respectively (`a=*10` is equal to `a=a*10`). Then we use the Output Field Separator `"\t"`, which is a tab.

Comment: you forgot the `OFS` +1 is pending... :)

Comment: Oh, @Kent, I though you were already on weekend :) Thanks for pointing it out, the output is way nicer this way!

Comment: I've been told the sun will appear at 6pm, no matter where we are :D

Comment: @fedorqui The solution does not work correctly. The columns values shift to left for null values. Row 2 and 3 have shifted in your solution

Comment: @SantoshPillai now I see. Well, awk squeezes the text in the beginning, so that all the empty columns will be shifted. To make it work, fill empty spaces with some text (0, -, etc).